# how to parse through a .txt file and move all files into another directory

Tags: bash

Issue:

I have a txt file that looks like this:

```
SRA1202321.sra
SRA123221.sra
SRA1209312.sra
```

I have a directory that looks like this:

```
SRA1202321.sra
SRA123221.sra
SRA1209312.sra
random.sra
random.sra
```

I want to move all of the files from the .txt to a a different directory and leave behind the ones that I do not want.  I am new to bash so Im having a bit of trouble doing this.

I have tried:

```sh
cat ~working/metasamples.txt |
xargs mv ~/ncbi/public/sra/metasamples/
```

but it seems there is new lines characters being catted in so it says no directory exists.  I am currently looking at bash scripts and have this idea also:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

while read p; do
  mv "$p" ~/ncbi/public/sra/metasamples/
done <~/working/metaSRAfromjsoncorrected.txt
```

However Im not sure how to remove new lines?  Part of that has to do with im confused why input file is given last and if I can just adjust the variable like in python.  Sorry if its a bit confusing.

Thanks for any help

Comment: xargs breaks the input on spaces (so you will run into trouble with this approach if you have filenames with with spaces in them), and it appends the filename by default at the *end* of the command, so you will end up with i.e. `mv ~/ncbi/public/sra/metasamples/ SRA1202321.sra`, which is not what you want.

Comment: _how to remove new lines_ : What "new lines" are you talking about exactly? Why don't you run your _while_ loop with `set -x` turned on and post here the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably a problem of CRLF line endings. Instead of `cat` you can use (in bash):

```sh
sed $'s/\r$//' ~working/metasamples.txt |
xargs -I {} mv {} ~/ncbi/public/sra/metasamples/
```

That will work as long as the filenames in `metasamples.txt` don't contain any problematic character

Comment: Thank you very much!  That was literally it.  Also thank you for editing my post, I realized it did not format right but you beat me to it.  Thank you again